# Google Server Key API restriction is not removed

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-console

I noticed a strange behaviour in the Google API Console.
I added an IP Adress restriction on a server key and everything worked fine: the restriction was behaving as expected.
However I afterward tried torevert back to the "no restriction" situation.
The console did not show any error and the restriction seems removed (I have again the yellow alert notice), however the restriction is still blocking the Google cloud messages I'm trying to send from a previous unauthorized IP adress.

For instance I cannot simply add the new IP adress, since it may vary.

Do you know if I'm doing something wrong?

[image: Message saying there is no restriction on the key]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about issues with the Google developer console.  Author should flag an issue on Google developer console.

Comment: I posted the question because I'm not sure it is an issue because I did not find anyone with similar problem and was wondering that I maybe need to do something more to remove the restriction